# how to apply a specific regex to a specific line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to apply a specific regex on a specific line, specified by the starting key:
Right now I have the content of my file inside the python variable my_config

---

```
file content
---------------------------------------------
[paths]
path_jamjs: C:/Users/[changeUsername]/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jamjs/bin/jam.js
path_php: C:/[changeUsername]/php/php.exe

values to replace
---------------------------------------------
"path_jamjs": { "changeUsername": "Te" },
"path_php": { "changeUsername": "TeS" },
```

---

```
with open ("my.ini", "r") as myfile:
  my_config = myfile.read()
```

**How can I apply a regex replace on the entire file content that is in my_config that will replace the value at the specific corresponding line, without having to loop line by line, can I do this with regex?**

given

```
path: path_php
key: changeUsername
value: Te
```

CHANGE

```
path_jamjs: C:/Users/[changeUsername]/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jamjs/bin/jam.js
path_php: C:/[changeUsername]/php/php.exe
```

TO

```
path_jamjs: C:/Users/[changeUsername]/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jamjs/bin/jam.js
path_php: C:/Te/php/php.exe
```

Comment: Before jumping into regex / string replacement, what format of configuration file is this? The ``[path]`` looks like ``ini`` format which you can use ConfigParser. However, you have `:` colon which makes it more like YAML. If you are responsible for writing the configuration file, choose one. Either ``.ini`` or ``.yaml``. I'd go with YAML personally. But depends on your preference.

Comment: Yes this is .ini for ConfigParser, I have no preference, whatever works right!

Comment: @user391986 : [``re.sub``](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't remember if ``.ini`` actually allows you to use ``:`` instead of ``=``. But in general, you can read the ini file off ConfigParser. And yeah what Schorsch suggests. But if you have a specific string to replace, you can easily replace the string by doing a search after reading from configparser, because you can access by section and access the key (path_jamjs, for example) and work on the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open ("my.ini", "r") as myfile:
    my_config = myfile.read()

lines = my_config.splitlines(True)
replacements = {"path_jamjs": {"changeUsername": "Te"},
                "path_php": {"changeUsername": "TeS"}}

for path, reps in replacements.items():
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith(path + ':'):
            for key, value in reps.items():
                line = line.replace('[' + key + ']', value)
            lines[i] = line

result = ''.join(lines)
```

Comment: It's an ini file. Have him fix that, he just need to use ConfigParser. No need read() and splitlines.  Otherwise it's oaky though... +1

Comment: CppLearner, my issue is that I am using ConfigParser however ConfigParser has paths that contain variables. So I have another file which are user specific variables that get substituted into the .ini before ConfigParser reads it which is why I'm looking for above solution.

Comment: This looks great F J! Testing it out now

Comment: amazing, thanks alot, the only difference I did was used iteritems() instead of items() as my json file was from json.load

Comment: F J the last thing to get this working for me perfectly is once I have the result string, I need to feed this in  config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()    then  config.readfp(StringIO.StringIO().write(result))  is this right? I can't seem to access my options though

Comment: Good point, I was just curious if you could do it with some regex but I really don't have that many lines so since this was simple enough I still like it!

Comment: It could be done with regex, but this way is more clear.  It would end up being something like `re.sub(r'^('+path+':.*)\['+key+'\]', r'\1'+value', my_config, flags=re.M)`.

Comment: that's awesome! Well I would put two check-marks if I could :) Thanks again